# An optimal alternative to embedding llply() inside llply() for matching objects in a list?

Tags: r, list, optimization, plyr

I am writing a path finder in R which finds all paths (at n distance) from one list of nodes (represented as node objects) to another list of nodes (represented as node objects). To speed up path discovery, I build the paths in two directions. Then, as a final step, I check to see if the nodes intersect.

In short, I am running through one list of nodes against another list of nodes, looking for *all* matches. The code works, however, it runs very slow. Does anyone have any suggestions for how I could re-write this code for better optimization?

```
unlist(llply(list.nodepath.1,
             # For each node.1 in list.nodepath.1...
             function(node.1){
               llply(list.nodepath.2,
                     # And for each node.2 in list.nodepath.2...
                     function(node.2){
                       if(node.1@internode == node.2@internode){
                         cat("Connection found!...\n")
                         # Merge node objects, including meta-data (defined elsewhere)
                         intersect(node.1, node.2)
                       }
                     })
              })
        )
```

I have tried parallelization; however, I can't seem to get llply(.parallel = TRUE) to work with this function...

According to Rprof() performance analysis, the bottleneck seems to have something to do with the llply() call -- not the intersect() function.

I appreciate any suggestions on restructuring this code.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the [TSP](http://r-forge.r-project.org/projects/tsp/) package? Your problem reads like a variant of the problems addressed there; an example of its use follows:

```
> ## load library and read data
R> library("TSP")
R> data("USCA312")

R> ## create a TSP object from the data 
R> tsp <- TSP(USCA312)
R> tsp

object of class 'TSP'
312 cities (distance   'euclidean')

R> ## find a 2-optimal solution 
R> tour <- solve_TSP(tsp, method = "2-opt")
R> tour
```

Answer (score 0):

You may find that simply using lapply() is more efficient than llply(). For example,

```
L1 <- as.list(letters)
L2 <- list("f", "h", "k", "m")

unlist(lapply(L1, function(l) {
  lapply(L2, function(m) {
    if (l == m) {
      print("match found")
      return(m)
    }
  })
}))
```